# Check if a variable has significantly different effects in 2 samples

Tags: model-comparison, lm

I have a variable (Y) measured on 2 different samples (X, 0=clinical, 1=control). I verified that a third variable (BMI, 3 classes) has an interaction with Y based on point plots by plotting X,Y for each BMI class. The interaction seems to be at the level of intercept and slope.

I want to assess weather the interaction is significant for each variable X.
I have 2 options in mind:

1. linear regression for each sample Y~BMI and check if the coefficients for each class are significant for both models (X). Though, I would need to verify if the models are significantly different too (how? Say in python or R)
2. linear mixed model with Y~X+(X|BMI). But how do I verify whether BMI is relevant? Also, I don't think I have enough data.

Also (different problem), does this analysis allows me to understand if is the BMI or X that is causing the variation Y? Or comparing a model with BMI vs X as grouping variable (output Y) and check for the residual variance is a better method?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the question and would propose a more detailed description of what you are doing. E.g.,  "I have a set of variables (Y) " - so there are different $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, \dots$? If so, how do you compute Y ~ BMI? "I verified ... based on plots" - why don't you show the plot? "causing the variation Y" so Y is a variation as well as a set of variables? Is X one variable describing two groups or are there two variables, both called X? I think this is going to end in a linear regression of sth like `lm(Y ~ X * BMI, ...)` but I might misunderstand the whole thing, as well.

Comment: So, let's consider Y is one variable. X is a binary variable.

Comment: An interaction is usually between two predictor variables (e.g. Y ~ X * BMI), not between a predictor variable and the outcome. If the outcome varies according to the predictor doesn't that simply mean that the two are related? If you want to test whether the effect of group (X) on the outcome (Y) depends on a third factor (BMI), then you might want to look at Y ~ X * BMI. Unless I misunderstand the question completely

Comment: As you referred 'An interaction is usually between two predictor variables': actually BMI and the continuous variable are my predictors for the binary variable. But I have always seen the categorical variable in x axis, so I assumed it should be treated as dependent (as you shown). Now, I am wondering if I should do the other way around.

Comment: Example: https://ademos.people.uic.edu/Chapter13_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-17-1.png

Comment: Any thoughts on my previous comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll try an answer hoping, I got the question right.
First we need some data. As none was given, let'S construct the following example data `expl`:

```
expl <- data.frame(x = gl(2,30, labels = c("clinical", "control")),
                   bmi = sample(gl(3,20, labels = c("under", "normal", "over"))))
expl$y <- 5 * as.integer(expl$x) + 2*as.integer(expl$bmi) + rnorm(10, 1)
plot(expl$y ~ expl$x)
plot(expl$y ~ expl$bmi)
```

From simple graphics we can see that `y`depends on `x` as well as on `bmi`:

[image]

Let's further analyse this via the call to `lm` I proposed in my comment:

```
> model <- lm(y ~ x * bmi, data = expl)
> print(summary(model))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x * bmi, data = expl)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.7638 -0.4012 -0.1459  0.4754  0.9709 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         7.89100    0.19969  39.516  < 2e-16 ***
xcontrol            5.08647    0.24768  20.536  < 2e-16 ***
bminormal           1.90510    0.26036   7.317 1.26e-09 ***
bmiover             4.30579    0.24768  17.384  < 2e-16 ***
xcontrol:bminormal  0.07958    0.34231   0.232    0.817    
xcontrol:bmiover   -0.22218    0.35028  -0.634    0.529    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5283 on 54 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9663,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9632 
F-statistic: 309.7 on 5 and 54 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Let's start looking at `x` values and neglect the interaction terms for the time being. For the `x == "clinical"` group, the Intercept ist `(Intercept)` of 7.89 plus or minus what the interactions terms will say. For the `x == "control"` group the Intercept will be `(Intercept) + xcontrol`, thus 7.89 + 5.09. `xcontrol` is the difference in the Intercepts of `clinical` and `control` and `lm` tells us, that this difference is highly significant.

The same can be said about the `bmi` groups: The reference group is underweight (`under`) and for all those who are `normal` we add 1.91 and can easily see that that is significantly different from zero. For all those who are `over` we add 4.31 and can see that that is significantly different from zero.

So as we modelled both `x` groups and all three `bmi` groups *within one model* we can deduct from their coefficients' significance whether belonging to a certian group makes a differenct in Intercept. As we only have group predictors and no continuous predictors there are no slopes to be considered here. If they were, the approach would be the same.

In our example the interaction terms have small coefficients which are not significant so there is not much point in interpreting them but if they were worthwhile, each of their coefficents describes how large the deviance from the simple model without interactions is and whether it is significant.

In the likely case that you'll want `normal` to be the reference level instead of `under` R has the `relevel` command for that:

```
> summary(lm(y ~ x + bmi, data = expl))$coefficients
            Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 8.486852  0.3363842 25.229639 2.887104e-32
xcontrol    5.000000  0.3363842 14.863956 4.321901e-21
bminormal   2.029344  0.4119848  4.925774 7.809338e-06
bmiover     4.354841  0.4119848 10.570392 5.893605e-15
> expl$bmi <- relevel(expl$bmi, "normal")
> summary(lm(y ~ x + bmi, data = expl))$coefficients
             Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 10.516197  0.3363842 31.262455 3.872745e-37
xcontrol     5.000000  0.3363842 14.863956 4.321901e-21
bmiunder    -2.029344  0.4119848 -4.925774 7.809338e-06
bmiover      2.325497  0.4119848  5.644618 5.711254e-07
```

Comment: Thank you that is very well explained.